# How Do We Explain Data In Number Sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do we explain what skewed (left, right, or symmetrical) a data set of numbers is? How can we find it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skewness in a graph of data](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316152/skewness-in-a-graph-of-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize the dataset by plotting it in a histogram. If it is roughly symmetric, then it is symmetric. If it has a longer tail to the right, then it is skewed right, and if it has a lot of bars on the right but a longer tail on the left, then it is skewed left.

The mean would be less than the median for skewed left data, as the lower extremities pull the mean down. The median would be higher than the mean as the concentration of data points on the right side keeps the median in their ballpark.